# Unable to connect to X11 Server through XOpenDisplay

Tags: linux, virtualbox, x11-forwarding

I'm running two virtual machines on the same host. One with Ubuntu the other with Red Hat. Both vms have are set to the same NAT Network on VirtualBox. I am able perform X11 forwarding from one vm to another and vice versa with ssh username@ip -X.

For the sake of this example let's say the ip of the vm I'm trying to connect to is 178.23.2.6 and the input I give to XOpenDisplay is 178.23.2.6:0 since I want to connect to display 0 on the server side. I'm not sure if I'm giving the wrong input or not, but when I try running a program with XOpenDisplay it keeps giving the error `"RuntimeError: Cannot connect to 178.23.2.6:0: Unknown error"` Any input regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the X server only accepts local connections (over the local Unix socket "/tmp/.X11-unix/X0") – it does not listen for TCP connections at all. To allow that, configure your display manager (GDM, SDDM, LightDM) to start the X server with the `-listen tcp` option.

- For example, with GDM you have to add `DisallowTCP=false` in the `[security]` section of /etc/gdm/custom.conf.
- With LightDM you need `xserver-allow-tcp=true` in the `[SeatDefaults]` section of /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.

(SSH X11 forwarding works because you're not directly connecting to the X server over the network; you're connecting to 'localhost', the data is relayed over SSH, and the SSH daemon also connects to the "local" socket on the remote side.)

After TCP is enabled, `ss -ltn` or `netstat -ltn` should show a listening TCP socket for display+6000, e.g. if your display is `:0`, Xorg will be listening on TCP port `6000`, and so on. You'll need to allow inbound connections through the firewall (ufw, etc.) – make sure to do it carefully and not allow connections from the whole Internet.

The X server will also require either authentication through the Xauthority file (the "magic cookie" has to be copied from server to client) or through the trusted hosts list (the client's IP address has to be allowed). Either one is enough.

- To use Xauthority, run `xauth list :0` on the X server, copy the authentication cookie to the client, and import it using `xauth add 178.23.2.6:0 <type> <cookie>` on the X client.
- To use Xhosts, run `xhost +178.23.2.XYZ` on the server.
- Don't run `xhost +` on its own, as it *completely* disables all authentication checks.

Finally, keep in mind that X11 connections are not encrypted in any way.